# Can Replication on CouchDb be Faster on Production Server

Tags: couchdb

Please forgive me if this should be posted elsewhere...

I have a production couchDb server that has about 40 databases running. There is one database that has 100,000+ records and weighs in at about 2GB. It is a database that holds both html and user records.

When making changes to the site through the database, I make a continuous backup of the database so as to not lose new records. When I'm finished updating the prerelease copy of the production database, I make a backup of the production database, and then delete the production database. I then replicate the prerelease database to the production database (since I can't simply rename it).

The process of replicating the database and then the process of updating the views takes up to 30 minutes. It would take longer if I didn't disable the site from hitting the database as it continuously starts over when users hit the site.

My questions are this: 
Is my general process of updating the database flawed? I don't want to make changes to a production database while users are hitting it.

Is there any way to speed up the process of the replication/updating of the views?

I basically came up with this process on my own and haven't found any best practices for this type of maintenance.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: It sounds like you have one step too many, but I have a couple of questions.
Why do you need to rename your databases? In your 3rd paragraph you say you "update the site through the database," could you clarify how you do that? Is it a couch app?
If you have a production database, and you make changes to that as well as a dev database, you should be able to replicate your dev database to that prod database, and keep all the new records unless there are conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I don't really need to rename the db's; I just want to make the updated version into the production version without the significant delay. However I don't think I would want productionV1,V2, V3, etc. As far as the replication goes, it has been my experience from earlier that the dev version would basically overwrite the prod version. For example, in futon, the dev version would have roughly 200 records. After replication, the dev version would go from 100000+ records to the 200. I will test this again though, as this was when I 1st used couchDb.

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly you're trying to achieve, without going into your (current) solution? I somehow have the feeling that you're trying to do too much.

Comment: Thanks, So we have both user sessions and View data (html) mixed in the same couchdb instance. When doing updates to the html of the site I can't lose the user session data, so I am wanting to update the db without making changes directly to the production instance. That's why I'm using a replicated copy of the production db to make changes to. Please let me know if this is too vague, I appreciate the help.

Comment: When you say "update the db", are you making changes to indexes/design documents or data?

Comment: Sorry...holidays. Just data docs. Thanks